# AngularJs Directive - Re render html when adding new angular attribute

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, typescript

my problem is basically make the compiler getting a new attribute i've added in a directive.
I'm using typescript and i have something like this.

```
public class MyDirectiveScope: ng.IScope
{
    foo: boolean;
}

public class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective
{        
    public restrict = 'A';

    public scope = {
        foo:'=',

    };

    public constructor (protected $log: ng.ILogService)
     {

     }

    link = ($scope: MyDirectiveScope, element: JQuery, attributes: ng.IAttributes)
    {
        if(!$scope.foo)
        angular.element(element).attr("ng-if","false");
    }
}
```

The element where i call my directive get the new attribute i've added, but angular is not evaluating this new attribute. If i have a `<div>` element for example that gets this new attribute and will be something like `<div ng-if="false">,` i want that whats will be inside the div will not be displayed.

I've used before angular.element(element).css("display", "none") and this works, but i really want the div element not be in the DOM at all.

Comment: Try to do it at compile stage of directive building instead of link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamically setting directive attributes should be avoided and certainly goes against best practices. You should use`<div ng-if="checkCondition">` in your template, and can modify the logic in your `checkCondition` function. Even if there are a few possible attributes you should add them all to the element and put the logic within a function.

If you must use this approach you can destroy and re-create the directive with the attributes you require like this:

```
var element = $compile("<my-directive someAttribute=\"someval\"")($scope);
```

You can then append `element` into your DOM however you see fit.

Comment: Hum i see, i'm using my directive as an attribute so i have something like <div my-directive>, to replace my attribute after using the $compile function i have to do something like element.replaceWith() right?